# RSA crypto - How to choose p, q and e correctly?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Recently I've found some troubles after having those **e**, **n** and **d** value.
I had this set 
`(p=3, q=11)`

so `n = 33` and `Euler(n)=20`.
I choose 
`e=3`, calculated `d = 7`.
For message `x=49`, the signature would be 
`s = x^d mod n = 49^7 mod 33 = 2`5.
Someone would verify it like `ver(s) = s^e mod n = 16 != x (Fake?)`

What 've I done wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, not programming. http://crypto.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: In modular arithmetic (modulo 33) 16 and 49 = 16 + 1 * 33 are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answerer rather (too) succinctly put - naive RSA will only recover the exact original value when it is *less than* the modulus (`n`). Your message `x = 49` is larger than your modulus (`n = 33`), so you will not be able to decrypt the ciphertext back to the original value of `x`.

If you were to try again with a smaller message, e.g. `x = 25` things will work fine:

Encrypt:

```
C = xe mod n
  = 253 mod 33
  = 16
```

Decrypt:

```
x = Cd mod n
  = 167 mod 33
  = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not wrong:

49=16 mod 33